# Qt6 Android CMake project fails to find Qt component "Core"

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6

I have a problem when I create a new `QtQuick` project with `Qt6 android` with `CMake`. The CMake fails immediately after the creation of the project:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):

Found package configuration file:

C:/Qt/6.0.0/android_armv7/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
FOUND.  The reason is given by package:

Failed to find Qt component "Core" config file at ""

Failed to find Qt component "Quick" config file at ""
```

I am on `Windows` and this error occurs with every qt6 android kit(x86, x86_64, armv7, arm64).

What is causing this problem? I have tried to solve it and I found similar bugs already reported but still could not find a solution. Any suggestion or help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I noticed too, that after I install new android kit(for example 5.12.10 x86 and armv7) via `MaintenanceTool` all my Qt6 android kits are deleted. But msvc and mingw Qt6 kits are not deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this same problem but for Windows Desktop compilation. I just add the prefix path folder, before `find_package` command:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:\\Qt\\6.1.2\\msvc2019_64)
```

NOTE that it is just a half of the path to file.

If I well understand, in your situation you should add:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/Qt/6.0.0/android_armv7)
```

After that you may recived problem with missing dll. This can by solve by adding neceserii path to your system PATH. In may situation it was:

```
C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\bin
C:\Qt\6.1.2\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms
```